# magento access denied

Tags: api, magento, rest, oauth

I have installed Magento 1.7.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.0.4 server and everything works.

Testing REST API with an admin role (http://1.2.3.4/magento/api/rest/products) I get this result:

```
<magento_api>
  <messages>
    <error>
      <data_item>
      <code>403</code>
        <message>Access denied</message>
      </data_item>
    </error>
  </messages>
</magento_api>
```

I have created an admin role grant all access on all and the token authentication procedure was ok.

I've tried with magento go service, Bitnami VM and Windows installer but seems that web services are not present (I can see only user/role under Web Services).

Did you know of a magento setup with REST API working?

How can I debug this kind of error? I have tried with different REST client.

Thanks!

Comment: hi, did you resolved this one? I'm having the same problem. I was checking and Magento is calculating the wrong signature for POST.

If you check /app/code/core/mage/oauth/model/server.php line 535. $this->_params that are put in signing function include signature sent by client what is - by my understanding a bug?

Comment: I had the same issue but I was trying to access Admin functionalities with the example of Customer login. So it failed of course.
Here is the good way to do it if you want to access with the admin permission http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Answer (score 3):

Did you set permissions for roles and attributes? If not check do it first magentocommerce.com/api/rest/permission_settings/

Comment: Good link at http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/permission_settings/permission_settings.html

Answer (score 1):

I have once tested REST API for magento..

I following blogs helped me to setup the REST Api

[1.first](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html)

[2.second](http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/)

[3.third](http://www.digitalblend-cl.com/blog/index.php/articles/website-documents/207-magento-rest-and-oauth-to-the-party)

I used RESTClient addon for firefox for testing and be sure that Oauth is enabled at server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below post.This may be helpful to you.

[Oauth rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857981/error-while-using-rest-api-in-magento)

and also

[Get product using admin user](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html).

Comment: Can you help me regard rest api customer getting error : https://snag.gy/MVINwS.jpg @Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chanz up there, I found the solution to my own issue.

> It doesn’t seem to accept the OAuth parameters as query string
>   parameters. I tried sending them as HTTP headers instead and it’s
>   going through.

source: http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/comment-page-1/#comment-5090

Surely, make sure you have the right settings at `System > Web Services > Web Roles` and `System > Web Services > Web Attributes`.

It is also helpful to use the [Ruby oAuth library](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/) because "it’s clean, simple and works well". See post [there](http://www.aschroder.com/2012/04/introduction-to-the-magento-rest-apis-with-oauth-in-version-1-7/).

Answer (score -2):

You should try these for this problem in api:-

1)change the value in the file /app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php, change the value of:
DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'guest'
to
DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'admin'.

2)change the value in the file /app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php, 
change this line from 
return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE, 'id' => null); 
to this:
return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE, 'id' => '1');
(note:only change null to '1').

3)restart your server(for apache run this command: sudo service apache2 restart).
i hope these steps will solve your 403 access denied problem.