# Python 2.7, Magento Community 1.8 API connection issues

Tags: php, python, windows, magento, python-2.7

I am using the [python-magento API](https://github.com/voberoi/python-magento) with little luck making a connection. This API is attempting to use Magento's [XML-RPC](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) and connection to Community Magento 1.8...

My local install is Python 2.7 (64) on Windows 8, while Magento is on a PHP 5.4 stack.

### After a few alterations and a handful of API's used, this is the primary error with python-magento API, attempting connection from Pycharm and DataNitro...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/PYTHON/magento_test_connect.py", line 2, in <module>
magento = MagentoAPI("xxx.com", 80, "userxxx", "passxxx")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\magento\__init__.py", line 20, in __init__
self.login()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\magento\__init__.py", line 59, in login
self._session_id = self._client.login(self._api_user, self._api_key)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
verbose=self.__verbose
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
return self.parse_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
return u.close()
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 2: 'Access denied.'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was looking for some direction, but now I am going to throw a bounty as I see making a connection to Magento with Python is not documented well on the web.

The code I have scaled down to is...

```
from magento import *
magento = MagentoAPI("xxx.com", 80, "userxxx", "passxxx")
magento.help() #just to see some results
```

going to the direct url path (to check on firewall issues), I get...

```
<methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><int>630</int></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value><string>Unable to read request</string></value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>
```

I have entered all of the details into Magento admin and gave full privileges. Thought about using the REST API, but after reading this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567915/magento-access-denied?rq=1), looks to be having the same issues.

**

### Changing up my code a bit...

**

```
import magento
url = 'xxx.com'
port = 8080
apiuser = 'userxxx'
apipass = 'passxxx'

with magento.MagentoAPI(url, port, apiuser, apipass) as product_api:
    order_filter = {'created_at':{'from':'2013-01-15 00:00:00'}}
    products = product_api.list(order_filter)
```

the error...

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

### I was able to set this up on another Magento install and it worked, showing...

```
Resources:

cart: create, info, license, order, totals
cart_coupon: add, remove
cart_customer: addresses, set
cart_payment: list, method
cart_product: add, list, moveToCustomerQuote, remove, update
cart_shipping: list, method
catalog_category: assignProduct, assignedProducts, create, currentStore, delete, info, level, move, removeProduct, tree, update, updateProduct
catalog_category_attribute: currentStore, list, options
catalog_product: create, currentStore, delete, getSpecialPrice, info, list, listOfAdditionalAttributes, setSpecialPrice, update
catalog_product_attribute: addOption, create, currentStore, info, list, options, remove, removeOption, types, update
catalog_product_attribute_media: create, currentStore, info, list, remove, types, update
catalog_product_attribute_set: attributeAdd, attributeRemove, create, groupAdd, groupRemove, groupRename, list, remove
catalog_product_attribute_tier_price: info, update
catalog_product_custom_option: add, info, list, remove, types, update
catalog_product_custom_option_value: add, info, list, remove, update
catalog_product_downloadable_link: add, list, remove
catalog_product_link: assign, attributes, list, remove, types, update
catalog_product_tag: add, info, list, remove, update
catalog_product_type: list
cataloginventory_stock_item: list, update
core_magento: info
core_store: info, list
customer: create, delete, info, list, update
customer_address: create, delete, info, list, update
customer_group: list
directory_country: list
directory_region: list
giftmessage: setForQuote, setForQuoteItem, setForQuoteProduct
sales_order: addComment, cancel, hold, info, list, unhold
sales_order_creditmemo: addComment, cancel, create, info, list
sales_order_invoice: addComment, cancel, capture, create, info, list, void
sales_order_shipment: addComment, addTrack, create, getCarriers, info, list, removeTrack, sendInfo

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Isn't that firewall issue? Are you able to connect with this remote host on port 8080 by simply pasting url into web browser? No matter what response you'll get this way - it is important to check if server would actually answer your request.

Comment: I could view using url in browser but no response passed in the XML given except what I appended to my question.

Answer (score 0):

After many tests, a 1.7 install worked while the 1.8 remained under block on the same server and configurations. The only conclusion is 1.8 is not completed for API use and this issue is (as of 6/23/13) a 1.8 Magento bug.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thread originator is still having an issue but I ran into problems with [python-magento](https://github.com/voberoi/python-magento) and xmlrpc with Magento 1.8.

```
from magento import *
m = MagentoAPI('mag1', 80, 'user', 'pass')
```

fails with

```
<ProtocolError for mag1:80/magento/api/xmlrpc: 404 Not Found>
```

The default PATH in python-magento is /magento/api/xmlrpc.

Changing this to '/index.php/api/xmlrpc' worked for me:

```
m = MagentoAPI('mag1', 80, 'user', 'pass', path='/index.php/api/xmlrpc')
```

succeeds.

Problem caused by new rewrite processing in Magento 1.8. See here for more info:
[Magento API error when accessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903567/magento-api-error-when-accessing).

Hope this helps.

Jerry.