# Magento API error when accessing

Tags: api, magento

When I try to access the API, i get an error, i start the connection with this:

```
$api = new SoapClient(BASE_URL."/api/?wsdl");
```

Note: The URL is fine.

I've been making a plugin, and it worked on my 1.7.0.2 version, but now I tried on a 1.7.0.2 version in another person Magento, and it reports an error.

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:152:"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://WEBSITE.com//api/?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://WEBSITE.com//api/?wsdl" 
";i:1;s:3536:"#0 /var/www/clients/client20/web25/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/moloni/classes/core.class.phtml(283): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://WEBSITE...')
```

When I try to access that page, if i'm logged in the backoffice, the XML api file show's up well, but if I start a private session, it doesn't return nothing.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable API calls in your .htaccess file. Remove '#' in the line

```
#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT**
This line add URL rewrite rule for webserver rewrite engine which redirect all /api/[type] calls to api.php file. You want to avoid using RewriteEngine for your API calls you can try to use api.php directly, like this

```
$api = new SoapClient(BASE_URL."/api.php?type=soap");
```

The type parameter specify which protocol you want to use. Out of the box magento support xmlrpc, soap, soap_v2 and rest.

Comment: Where is that line? In the root folder it doesn't have a .htaccess there, can I create it? :)

Comment: This file bundled with Magento core, may be you can't find it because it's hidden. Try to enable 'show hidden files' in your file manager. You can download sample .htacess file from official Magento repository - http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/.htaccess

Comment: If you want to avoid using RewriteEngine for your API calls you can try to use api.php directly, like this $api = new SoapClient(BASE_URL."/api.php?type=soap");

Comment: BTW, if you open URL http://WEBSITE.com//api/?wsdl in your browser you may see more details about your the problem.

Comment: if I try to load it like that, i get this error: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://perfumesbook.com/index.php/?type=soap&wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://perfumesbook.com/index.php/?type=soap&wsdl=1"
</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: It just gives a blank page if i'm not logged, if im logged on the backoffice, it goes ok :s

Comment: You should use api.php, not index.php. Try this URL - http://perfumesbook.com/api.php?type=soap&wsdl=1 it works fine for me. In browser and SoapClient as well.

Comment: Making progress :) Now I get this error a:5:{i:0;s:31:"Service Temporarily Unavailable";i:1;s:3815:"#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://perfumes...', 'urn:Mage_Api_Mo...', 1, 0), but the URL worked, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that following the services are enabled `S0AP, php_openssl, openssl, curl` 
these services should be enabled.

call soap client like `$api = new SoapClient('http://website.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');`

Comment: Yes, they are enable :)

Comment: I feel you should do the entry in host file for other

Comment: Nop, there is not a code like that in there s: And it doesn't even returns a error, it just returns a blank page when i try to access without beeing logged in the backoffice s:

Comment: try something like $api = new SoapClient('http://website.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');

Comment: Ok, i'il do that on another website to test it, accessing from a external website