# custom rest api have 403 error in magento

Tags: api, magento, rest, oauth

**i have create a custom rest api in magento.
it is working fine if i access via this code :**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html

**But when i want to access this using this url :**

host/api/rest/datafeed/truedash_customers

it is give me an error :

403 Access denied

can any one tell me why this happen any help please......

Comment: There moght be lots of situations where its happens... the most common is when the web server doesn't have sufficient permissions on the file/directory that you're trying to access. What server do you use? What operation system?  Do you have access to the operation system?

Comment: i am using apache server i am making this on my localhost.... sir please help me

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289525/custom-rest-api-have-403-error-in-magento

Comment: this is my question link sir i ask this question ??

Comment: Haha sorry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567915/magento-access-denied

Comment: yes sir the api what i have make it is showing in the admin as resource.. and i also have set permission but still not working

Answer (score 0):

1) Quick and dirty fix:
in the file /app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php, change the value of:
DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'guest'
to
DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'admin'.

In the file
/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php,
change this line from
return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE, 'id' => null);
to this:
return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE, 'id' => '1');

This way the authentication system will not be broken.

2) Proper and long run fix:
Override the two functionalities using the magento overriding mechanism to have a better solution in accordance to magento standards. This way the core files will be intact.

Answer (score -1):

1. Quick and dirty fix: in the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth.php`, change the value of: `DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'guest'` to `DEFAULT_USER_TYPE = 'admin'`.
2. In the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Auth/Adapter.php,` change this line from

   ```
   return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE,
                         'id' => null);
   ```

   to this:

   ```
    return (object) array('type' => Mage_Api2_Model_Auth::DEFAULT_USER_TYPE,
                          'id' => '1');
   ```

This way the authentication system will not be broken.